# Unable to parse XML data in Postman

Tags: xml, postman

I'm using Postman to send data. But I got error message `Unable to parse XML data`. Here is my link and parameters.

```
https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Accounts/insertRecords?newFormat=1&authtoken=xxxxx&scope=crmapi&xmlData=<Accounts>
<row no=“1”>
<FL val="SMOWNERID">2000000016714</FL>
<FL val="Lead Owner">Scott@zohotest.com</FL>
<FL val="Company">Zoho</FL>
<FL val="First Name">Peter</FL>
<FL val="Last Name">John</FL>
<FL val="Designation">CEO</FL>
<FL val="Email">john@test.com</FL>
<FL val="Phone">04422334455</FL>
<FL val="Fax">98889</FL>
<FL val="Mobile">09999999999</FL>
<FL val="Website">www.sample.com</FL>
<FL val="Lead Source">External Referral</FL>
<FL val="Lead Status">Contacted</FL>
<FL val="Industry">Financial Services</FL>
<FL val="No of Employees">100</FL>
<FL val="Annual Revenue">100.0</FL>
<FL val="Email Opt Out">true</FL>
<FL val="Skype ID">peter</FL>
<FL val="Salutation">Mr.</FL>
<FL val="Street">Street One</FL>
<FL val="City">Chennai</FL>
<FL val="State">Tamil Nadu</FL>
<FL val="Zip Code">6000001</FL>
<FL val="Country">India</FL>
<FL val="Description">Sample Description.</FL>
</row>
</Accounts>
```

Error message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Accounts/insertRecords">
    <error>
        <code>4835</code>
        <message>Unable to parse XML data</message>
    </error>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML attribute values may be delimited by `"` or `'`, but not `“` or `”`.

So change

```
<row no=“1”>
```

to

```
<row no="1">
```

and then your XML will be well-formed.